Antd Select component does not show more than 2 options in tests
After going crazy around a test that refuses to pass, I realized that the Select component in the Antd library does not handle more than 2 options. I wrote the following test to explore the issue:


import { Select } from 'antd';
import { render, screen, within } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';


describe('Select', () => {

  let user: ReturnType<typeof userEvent.setup>;

  beforeAll(() => {
    user = userEvent.setup();
  });

  it('shows more than 2 options', () => {
    function Tmp() {
      return (
        <Select>
          <Select.Option value='1'>1</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value='2'>2</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value='3'>3</Select.Option>
        </Select>
      );
    }

    render(<Tmp />);

    await user.click(screen.getByRole('combobox'));
    const options = screen.getAllByRole('option');
    
    expect(options).toHaveLength(3);
    expect(within(options[0]).getByText('1')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(within(options[1]).getByText('2')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(within(options[2]).getByText('3')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

});



This test fails. First it fails at the following line:
expect(options).toHaveLength(3);

It says that options only have a length of 2.
When I remove that line, the test fails at the last expect:
expect(within(options[2]).getByText('3')).toBeInTheDocument();

It says that options[2] is not an element. How can I make more options in the Select component available inside a test?

"antd": "^5.14.2"
The reason is virtual prop for <Select/> component is true by default. It will use virtual list. The test will work if virtual prop is set to false.
Besides, you forget to use async
import { Select } from 'antd';
import { render, screen, within } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from 'react';

describe('Select', () => {
  let user: ReturnType<typeof userEvent.setup>;

  beforeAll(() => {
    user = userEvent.setup();
  });

  it('shows more than 2 options', async () => {
    function Tmp() {
      return (
        <Select virtual={false}>
          <Select.Option value="1">1</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="2">2</Select.Option>
          <Select.Option value="3">3</Select.Option>
        </Select>
      );
    }

    render(<Tmp />);

    await user.click(screen.getByRole('combobox'));
    const options = screen.getAllByRole('option');

    expect(options).toHaveLength(3);
    expect(within(options[0]).getByText('1')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(within(options[1]).getByText('2')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(within(options[2]).getByText('3')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

Test result:
  Select
    √ shows more than 2 options (306 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.426 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.


Thanks! I did try that but it didn't work for me. But then I realized that you were using antd 5x. My project was using 4x. When I updated the library the problem was solved!
